# By setting a tspan=[to:very_small_step:tf], can it affect ode45 solver's step size?

Tags: matlab, ode

I have know that the `ode45` solver has adaptive step size controlled by Matlab program itself. The description below is given by [Matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ode45.html):

> Specifying tspan with more than two elements does not affect the internal time steps that >the solver uses to traverse the interval from tspan(1) to tspan(end). All solvers in the ODE >suite obtain output values by means of continuous extensions of the basic formulas. Although >a solver does not necessarily step precisely to a time point specified in tspan, the >solutions produced at the specified time points are of the same order of accuracy as the >solutions computed at the internal time points.

However, if I specify `very_small_step` in `tspan=[to:very_small_step:tf]`, will this affect program controlled step size. Will this force step size less than the value of `very_small_step`? OR matlab will make interpolation calculation to get the corresponding result at specified time point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your quote

> Specifying tspan with more than two elements does not affect the internal time steps

Also there exists the [MaxStep](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/odeset.html#f92-1039598) property to configure the maximum step size.
For steps in between the solvers use continuous extension formulas as described [here](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/odeset.html#oderefine).

Why are you asking anyway? What problem do you encounter?